# Access properties of an html element injected with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a small project which implements CRUDs on a MySQL table using PHP and jQuery.
The table is injected into the layout this way:

```
<?php

require '../connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT id, countryName, shortDesc FROM countries";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<table>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Country</th>
              <th>Short description</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>";

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["countryName"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["shortDesc"]."</td>
                  <td>
                      <button id='show' value=".$row["id"].">Show</button>  
                      <button id='edit' value=".$row["id"].">Edit</button>    // value field added to pass id data
                      <button id='delete' value=".$row["id"].">Delete</button> 
                  </td>
              </tr>";
    }
    
echo "</table>";

$conn->close();
?>
```

I added value fields to the buttons because I was thinking of using this property to pass the row's ID to the JS script which should load the EDIT page.

I used the event delegation to access the button but just after that i have no idea about accessing the value property of the button.

On my jQuery scripts file I wrote this code to test:

```
// EDIT
$('#content').on('click', '#edit', function() {       // EVENT DELEGATION
    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    var id = $('#content').children('#edit').attr("value");       

    alert( id );    // RETURN UNDIFINED
});
```

I tried to access a property of the content element and it work, so the problem should be that I cannot access his children like that (in a similar way to the even delegation with .on()).

there will probably be a more elegant way than this to solve the problem but in the meantime I would like to understand how to access the properties of AJAX injected HTML elements!

Comment: var id = $('#content').children('#edit')attr("value"); 
Did you missing the "." before attr ?

Comment: No, i just copied it wrong there cause i was trying to change it right now on my code, sorry!

Comment: Don't use the same `id` for multiple elements, that's what classes are for.

Comment: @quantumPuter I dont see any queries using concatenated values, so its unlikely

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but i m pretty sure i didn t repeat any id.

Comment: You create 3 buttons INSIDE A WHILE LOOP all with the same ID

Comment: You can use `var id = $(this).attr("value");` because jQuery sets the button as context for the function. Also, an `id` is supposed to be unique across the entire document, not just among its HTML siblings.

Comment: Oh i just noticed, thank you!!!

Comment: Ok it's working after changing id to class. Thank you all very mutch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have same `id` for mutliple elements change it to class then just use `$(this).attr("value")` to get value of edit button which is clicked.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
//get value
  var id = $(this).attr("value");
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Short description</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>
    <!--added class-->
      <button class='show' value="1">Show</button>
      <button class='edit' value="1">Edit</button>
      <button class='delete' value="1">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>ab2c</td>
    <td>ab2c</td>
    <td>
      <button class='show' value="2">Show</button>
      <button class='edit' value="2">Edit</button>
      <button class='delete' value="2">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Solved my problem and also clean my code quite a bit!

Answer (score 2):

Did you miss the "." before "attr" ?

```
var id = $('#content').children('#edit')attr("value");
```

And you are trying to create multiple items with same id via loop. That's why ajax can not detect the right item you want. Try adding it with unique identifier like id of item.

Comment: Just a copy error, but you are right! Edited

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with this code, you generally want to use classes for elements that are being repeated, like in the while loop in your php:

```php
...

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["countryName"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["shortDesc"]."</td>
                  <td>
                      <button class='show' value=".$row["id"].">Show</button>  
                      <button class='edit' value=".$row["id"].">Edit</button>    // value field added to pass id data
                      <button class='delete' value=".$row["id"].">Delete</button> 
                  </td>
              </tr>";
    }
```

Then you should be able to access the element using an event like this:

```js
$('#content .edit').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("value");

    alert( id );
});
```